# Paypal ExpressCheckout API showing different experience randomly

Tags: api, express-checkout

I am unable to find the answer to this question. Of late, the checkout process for customers alternates randomly between two different screens either directly as the paypal express checkout (1) or alternatively a paypal page (2).

(1) https://i.stack.imgur.com/atixBl.jpg
(2) https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNNWb.png

However, I don't want this random behaviour and would like the user experience to go straight through to the guest account and checkout as shown in link (2).

The api settings have been set to:

SOLUTIONTYPE: Sole
LANDINGPAGE: Billing
USERSELECTEDFUNDINGSOURCE: CreditCard

All other settings look correct in the paypal settings, but I am not able to connect directly all the time.

NB: I apologise for links as I am unable to post images.

Answer (score 0):

From everything I have read that is something you cant control.  Its paypals a/b testing.